# How do you pass Django csrf token in jquery validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, python, django, validation

I am trying to create a client side validation to see if a username has been taken upon registration. This validation is supposed to happen before the user submits the form.

In order to achieve this I am using the jquery validation plugin: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

The issue I'm having is that I am getting a 403 error:

```
POST example.com/check-username 403 (FORBIDDEN)
```

This is the code for the client side validation:
$(document).ready(function () {

```
      $('#register-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
          username: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
              url: "/check-username",
              type: "post",
              data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value,
                username: function() {
                  return $( "#id_username" ).val();
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      });
});
```

Here is my validate function in views.py:

```
def check_username(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', None)

    if not username:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid username")
    return User.objects.exists(username=username)
```

I suspect that this a csrf error but I'm not too sure how to do this to work alongside the jquery validation plugin. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/)?

Comment: In particular, the section on [Ajax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) which gives sample code showing exactly how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

step 1. Add input tag in your form with csrf name and hash

```
<input type="text" class="txt_csrfname" name="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?= $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>" hidden>
```

step 2. Get name & hash in your script

```
var csrfName = $('.txt_csrfname').attr('name');
   var csrfHash = $('.txt_csrfname').val();
```

step 3. send csrf token

```
<script>
       var csrfName = $('.txt_csrfname').attr('name');
       var csrfHash = $('.txt_csrfname').val();    

  $('#register-form').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
              username: {
                required: true,
                remote: {
                  url: "/check-username",
                  type: "post",
                  data: {
                    username: function() {
                      return $( "#id_username" ).val();
                    },
                    [csrfName]: function() {
                     return csrfHash;
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you definitely outputting the CSRF token to your form?

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

needs to be between your <form> tags.

Your code worked for me once I did that and modified your check_username view to return a proper HTTP Response.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def check_username(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', False)

    if not username:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest("Invalid username")
    return HttpResponse(User.objects.filter(username=username).exists())
```

Comment: I do have the csrf token between my form tags. Interesting that you got it to work without passing the csrf token in the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to what @Ashitosh Belge shared, this is what I did:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
        ...
        email: {
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url: "/validate/email/",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    username: function () {
                        return $("#id_email").val()
                    },
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: function () {
                        return $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        ...
    }
});
```